# Obtener el número de serie del disco en una sesión de usuario sin permisos de administrador

Tags: c#, windows

Tengo una aplicación que la he creado en dos modos, instalada y portable, y necesito obtener el número de serie del disco duro desde el que se ejecuta el programa. En modo portable es simplemente que se copian los binarios en una carpeta cualquiera y se ejecuta desde ahí.

Hasta ahora me había funcionado bien el código utilizando WMI, pero desde hace dos días está fallando en dos de los ordenadores cuando la utilizo en modo portable. Las cuentas de usuario no tienen privilegios de administración.

El código que utilizo es:

```
public static string GetDriveSerialNumber(string DriveLetter)
{
    string Filt = string.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=\"{0}:\"", DriveLetter);
    System.Management.ManagementObject O = new System.Management.ManagementObject(Filt);
    foreach (System.Management.PropertyData Prop in O.Properties)
    {
        if (Prop.Name == "VolumeSerialNumber")
        {
            return Prop.Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

La excepción que me salta es:

```
System.Management.ManagementException: Clase no válida
   en System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   en System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
   en System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_Properties()
   en enumdrvs.Program.GetDriveSerialNumber(String DriveLetter) en C:\workspace\Projects\PreviStorm\software\Host\playground\enumdrvs\Program.cs:línea 20
```

La línea donde salta el error es `foreach (System.Management.PropertyData Prop in O.Properties)`, que es cuando `ManagementObject` hace la consulta, al enumerarlo.

He probado con el siguiente código para hacer acceso al WMI, pero también tengo el error:

```
var driveQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive");

foreach (ManagementObject d in driveQuery.Get())
{ ...etc... }
```

¿Alguien más se ha encontrado con este error? ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Si utilizo botón derecho "Ejecutar como administrador" sigo teniendo el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La causa del problema era que la infraestructura de WMI se había corrompido y fue necesario repararla con la ayuda del colega de administración de la red.

Una herramienta que me resultó útil para realizar comprobaciones fue **WMI Code Creator**, que se puede descargar desde aquí -> [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572). Esta herramienta permite generar código en C# para tener acceso a parámetros específicos, es una buena ayuda para esos casos.

Desde una línea de comandos, con privilegios de administrador, con `winmgmt /verifyrepository` se puede comprobar la integridad de los datos de WMI, en mi caso decía que OK, pero no era del todo cierto porque faltaban todos los objetos de `Win32_DiskDrive`.

Fue necesario forzar la recuperación utilizando:

```
net stop winmgmt /y
winmgmt /salvagerepository
winmgmt /resetrepository
```

El programa se congelaba al ejecutarlo después de hacer estos pasos, pero después de reiniciar el ordenador, listo, todo de vuelta a la normalidad.